# How to get DSI pin out from CM3+ IO Board?

Tags: dsi

Read until the end before responding:
Here's the thing. I know the Compute Module IO Board Plus (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Compute_Module_IO_Board_Plus) has the DSI connectors next to the camera connectors. I'm not talking about those.

I want it from those Pins where you can use a female/male Jumper cables, just like the GPIOx pin outs:

[image]

BUT i just realized it's just for te GPIOx and some other things.

I need to connect the DSI 4 lanes DIRECTLY from the board not using their connector.
*(i have a custom hardware)*

But i can't see any pin-outs like the ones we get from GPIOx Banks.

Is it something they don't even have in that board?

Comment: `Is it something they don't even have in that board?`have you tried asking waveshare?

Comment: Don't they respond.